# Jmeter How to bulk evaluate CSV variables that have references to other

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, eval

Having two csv files loaded through CSV Data Set Config

CSV Data Set Config - csvfile1.csv

| var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | FFD |

CSV Data Set Config - csvfile2.csv

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `${var1}` | `${var2}` | Text |

How to bulk evaluate all the variables that has references to csvfile1.csv and end up with variable set like

```
col1 = ABC
col2 = FFD
col3 = Text
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand the ask. Why can't there be a csvfile2.csv with col1=ABC, col2=FFD, col3=Text. Could you please elaborate?
Or is your question around doing a join on csv files?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "bulk evaluate", but you could use the [`__eval` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) in all places where `col1` and `col2` are used:

```
${__eval(${col1})}
${__eval(${col2})}
```

This will not do any bulk operation but interpolate the values just-in-time.

Alternatively, you could pre-process the contents of the csvfile2.csv in a [Setup Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) and write the evaluated target values to a (third) csv file which you use in the main thread group(s).

Comment: The goal is to have some logic that will iterate over the row in CSV and if there is a reference ${} to automatically evaluate the variable.